# How to scroll QTableView to the position after the removed element / before the removed element?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qmodelindex

I have a simple table, where I implemented the `remove_row` method:

```
QModelIndexList list = this->docTable->selectionModel()->selectedRows();
if(!list.isEmpty())
{
    this->docTable->model()->removeRow(list.at(0).row());
    this->model->select();
}
```

Where `this->docTable` is a `QTableView` and my model is a `QSqlRelationalTableModel`:

```
this->docTable = new QTableView(this);
this->model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db);
this->model->setTable("name");
this->model->select();
this->docTable->setModel(this->model);
```

What I would like to do is to scroll `QTableView` to the position after/before the selected and deleted element. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can catch the signal [rowsRemoved()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsRemoved) of model and call [scrollTo()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#scrollTo) for the view.

Comment: @nabroyan but `scrollTo` what?

Comment: `rowsRemoved()` has parameters `start` and `end`. So you know which row(s) is/are deleted. You can pick up the next one, create a `QModelIndex` and pass it `scrollTo()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `scrollTo` the item you want to remove before you actually do that. When you remove the row afterwards the view should still be at the position of the removed row. In your example that would be

```
this->docTable->scrollTo(list.at(0));
this->docTable->model()->removeRow(list.at(0).row());
this->model->select();
```

Otherwise you can calculate the `QModelIndex` for the row before/after the removed row (if it exists). Since the position of the removed row is `list.at(0).row()`, the row before that is `list.at(0).row() - 1` (if `row() > 0`) and the following row is again at `list.at(0).row()` after the selected row has been removed. To retrieve the `QModelIndex` for that row use `index(newRow, 0, QModelIndex())` of your model.